# Neo4j graph database helping to store several time based data values, result of simulation

Tags: scala, geospatial, simulation, neo4j, graph-databases

We have existing simulation of system of cities written in scala ( https://forge.iscpif.fr/projects/simpop2/repository/revisions/dev/show/JSimpop) and using ABM (agent based models). Each city equal one agent in the simulation.

Imagine a Simcity like game or best, an Anno game like, with different cities localized in the world (environnement of our cities agents) which exchange differents type of values/goods following :

- A scope rule ( cities exchange data with other cities in a
  localized area, function of a scoping rule)
- Multiple market exchange rules (rules appear/change with time,
  because of urban function emergence into the simulation (for example
  industrial revolution add new rules, new scope for exchange), so city
  connection with other cities also change during time ... see here for
  more information about model rules
  http://www.simpop.parisgeo.cnrs.fr/models/simpop2/cities-a)

After simulation, we need to **export and visualize the data by time, by city, and by urban function**. So we choose to store all history of exchanges between cities during time of simulation into an hashmap with a "time" based key. This hashmap return an object territory which contain cities object + relation between cities + and all the values exchanged.

I'm not sure, but i think it's a good idea (a better idea than using Rdbms ?) to store data and this types of relation into spatial graph database (spatial neo4j https://github.com/neo4j/spatial or other better solution ?).

But i have multiple question about this solution (**if it is a good solution**) :

- Do you think i need to store a new graph at each time, or a big graph at the end only ?

  => So **how can i store time based attribute with this type of graph ?**
- Can i use this graph to make more complex queries about my existant spatialized graph (compute a star shortest path between cities, count number of interaction, etc.), and using these result into my simulation ?
- How can i export or import easily existing graph into my simulation ?

  => **So how can i map easily the graph object and the simulation agent object, considering the difficulty of a time based territory ?**

**Update 1**

Finally i choose neo4j with neo4j-spatial, and now i try to represent my problem with neo4j formalism. I take a more simple example to represent than the original question, and i think, if i can implement this formalism, this is a good use case (first ?) for future simulation data storage with neo4j !!

- City are represented with ABM ( one city = one agent agent in our model) in a spatial context (so one city = one node) communicate only with near neighbors (radius limit), at each step of simulation.
- City have a pool of innovation in their own market, other cities can get this innovation, one by step by city connected.
- At each step, one city try to copy one innovation of each neighboors with probability function of their distance, and after that, they try to innovate/ create new innovation.
- Graph of innovation is important, because i want to view the result of diffusion of any innovation in time (step of our simulation).
- It's complicated by the fact than innovation can disapear because each of them contain a life property after what we desactivate the possibility of diffusion.

[image]

I start a google shared diagram with my representation, if you can help me to correct, this is great :)

[draw](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1oW65bXJ-Z-B-vMzVwJb_qUmQvaunoEsajJm-QLRHB9Y/edit)

Thanks in advance for your advice,
SR

Answer (score 1):

How many events are we talking about? You could index the different time ranges as different layers in Neo4j Spatial, e.g. one layer per hour, and then search or analyze just the ones that are interesting.

Also, you could index them again by adding a time index construct (remember, the whole graph is intact and a topology), see e.g. http://blog.neo4j.org/2012/02/modeling-multilevel-index-in-neoj4.html

From the Geometry nodes you are dealing with in Neo4j Spatial indexes you can get to any connected domain nodes (like your events etc) and thus check anything during your traversal. See https://github.com/bartbaas/spatial/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/gis/spatial/pipes/GeoPipesTest.java for examples.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Here, we have thousand of exchanges between 100 or 1000 cities, and we need to store 1000, 2000 or 4000 sucessive state of territory without problem (one state by year for example, so we should need to store 4000 years of simulation)

Comment: 100.000 nodes for innovation object shared between time, 4000 step of times, 100 city, a mean of 5 or 10 exchange by city by step; it's very difficult to give more precise information about data collected because our model are stochastic, and innovation appear function of probability.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to emulate the schema design of OpenTSDB http://opentsdb.net/schema.html albeit the schema follows a Column family based approach (HBase) ...

Pay attention to the key design specifically as it provides the advantage of row grouping (by time slices) for time dimension based datasets